# Approximation of a real number via a fraction of coprimes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-approximation, coprime

I'm reading a paper on number theory (which is not my field at all) stating, without any proof, a claim which can be rephrased as

*Fix a positive integer $M$. Then, given any real number $\alpha$, there exist a positive integer $q\leq M$ and an integer $h$, such that:*

$(q, h)=1;$
$|q\alpha - h|\leq \tfrac{1}{M}.$

I can see that this is true for $M=1$, with $q=1$.

So far I've found the following. First, it is enough to find two integers $q>0$ and $h$ which satisfy $|q\alpha - h|\leq \tfrac{1}{M}$, without imposing that they are coprime. Indeed, we can write $q=mq'$ and $h=mh'$ with $q'$ an $h'$ coprime, and $|q'\alpha - h'|\leq \tfrac{1}{Mm}\leq\tfrac{1}{m}$.

Then we can assume that $\alpha\in[0,1)$. As if this is not the case, we can write $\alpha = n + \alpha'$, with $\alpha'\in[0,1)$ and if $h', q'$ solve the problem for $\alpha'$, then $h=h'+q'n$ and $q=q'$ solve it for $\alpha$.

Now essentially I still need to show that the set $[\alpha, 2\alpha, \dots, M\alpha]$ has at least one element which is closer than $1/M$ to the closest integer. How can I proceed to show this?

The paper I'm reading is *On Certain Sets of Integers* by K. F. Roth (1953). And the claim I have rephrased above is equation (5).

Comment: recommend Continued Fractions by Khinchin.   You might like Diophantine Approximation by Niven; he avoids continued fractions, there are various pigeonhole arguments instead, and he also talks about various sorts of approximation.  Meanwhile, your task here is satisfied by CF convergents to your real number. Indeed, a convergent $p/q$  with $q > 0$  satisfies $ \left\lfloor\alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right\rfloor < \frac{1}{q^2},$   corollary of Thm 9 on page 9 of Khinchin. Then $ \left\lfloor q\alpha - p \right\rfloor < \frac{1}{q},$

Comment: This is Dirichlet's approximation theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a way to prove the last step. Assume that it is false and that there is no integer $j$ between $1$ and $M$ such that the decimal part of $j\alpha$ is in $[0, 1/M]\cup[1-1/M,1]$. Then I have $M$ elements ($[\alpha, 2\alpha, \dots, M\alpha]$) whose decimal parts are all in $(1/M, 1-1/M)$. It follows that at least two of this elements (let's say $u\alpha$ and $v\alpha$) which have decimal parts less than $1/M$ far apart. Let's say that $u>v$. We have that $(u-v)\alpha\in[\alpha, 2\alpha, \dots, M\alpha]$ and its decimal part must be in $[0, 1/M]\cup[1-1/M,1]$, which is a contradiction.